# Calling a .gsp page

Tags: grails, gsp

I made a copy of index.gsp, called index_1.gsp and I like to call from an html page.

Since I did know how to call it from an html page I tried to call the index_1.gsp from a controller using the command: redirect(uri: "/index_1.gsp"), but failed.

I will appreciate it if you help me to call it either from html page or from a controller.
Thanks

Comment: You cannot call a GSP page from an HTML page.  The framework doesn't support it, and it wouldn't make sense.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot call a GSP from an HTML page.  It doesn't make sense.

If you want to render the view from a controller you can do something like this...

```
class SomeController {
    def someAction() {
        // this will render grails-app/views/some/index_1.gsp
        render view: 'index_1'
    }
}
```

Comment: If the GSP is in `grails-app/views/` instead of `grails-app/views/<some controller name>/` then you can render it with something like `render view: '/index_1'`.

Comment: **Many thanks for your prompt answer**. When I ran the suggested solution I got "The requested resource is not available, for index_1.jsp (gsp changed to **jsp**).

Comment: I am glad that I could help.